# PHP SHA256 and Salt won't work

Tags: php, sha256

I'm trying to create passwords that are sha256 hashed with a $salt variable to it. But for some reason it just won't work. Been working 3 hours on this now, and I'm about to rip my head off. Here is my code:

I'll try again, sorry ;o)

Ok, my script worked fine, untill I tried to add the sha256 to the passwords. I got a file for creating users which is:

```
$salt = "lollol";  
$password = hash('sha256', $salt.$_POST['password']);  
$sql = ("INSERT INTO members (username, password, name, last_name,company)VALUES('$username', '$password', '$name', '$last_name', '$company')")or die(mysql_error());

if(mysql_query($sql))
    echo "Your accuont has been created.";
```

It seems like it's correctly added to the Database. I can see that it is getting hashed with some letters and numbers.

But then when I'm trying to login, it just won't.

My code for login.php is:

```
$sql= "SELECT * FROM members WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";  
$result=mysql_query($sql);    
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);  
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);  
$password = $_POST['password'];  
$salt = "lollol";  
$auth_user = hash('sha256', $salt.$password);  
if($password == $salt.$auth_user){  
    echo "Logged in";  
} else {  
    echo "Not logged in";  
}
```

I got the idea of that, I have to encrypt password when I want to log in, but im not sure. I hope that some of you can help me.

Comment: Yes, that is way too much code.  Please try to cut your code snippet down to the *minimum* required to exhibit the problem.  At the moment, you have a mixture of validation, regexes, SQL, session variables and HTML generation.

Comment: You'd best just make a minimal example (the *very* least you could do is remove the comments, but in the end: just first explain what should happen, then show us some small piece of code, then explain what does happen and why this surpirses you. Helping will be easier like that!

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth I've eduted my question now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When trying to login you concatenate the hash with the salt once more

```
$auth_user = hash('sha256', $salt.$password);
if($password == $salt.$auth_user){ // <-- $salt once more
  echo "Logged in";
} else {
  echo "Not logged in";
}
```

It should work, if you just remove it

```
$auth_user = hash('sha256', $salt.$password);
if($password == $auth_user){
  echo "Logged in";
} else {
  echo "Not logged in";
}
```

Update: Going further

here

```
$sql= "SELECT * FROM members WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";
```

You try to retrieve the row, where the username matches `$username` and the password matches `$password`. In the database the passwords are already hashed (and `$password` seems to be not defined at all), thus this query will *never* return any row.

```
$password = hash('sha256', $salt.$_POST['password']);
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$sql= "SELECT * FROM members WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

`$result` should now contain the *only* user that matches the given credentials. Its now very easy

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result) === 1) {
  echo "Logged in";
} else {
  echo "Not logged in";
}
```

Comment: @KingCrunch It doesn't seem to work. Still won't echo "Logged in" out.

Comment: Note that this still doesn't make sense.  Now we're checking whether `$password == hash('sha256', $salt.$password)`!  (`$password` is on both sides of the `==`...)

Comment: @Ole Charlesworth I can see that. How should id be looking like?

Comment: @Oli: You are right. It must be the password out of `$row`. I'll update my answer. Update: Just realise, that the query is senseless too...

Comment: @KingCrunch And then now. Why can't you tell me how my sql should be like then?

Comment: @Kolind: ? I did :? I leave the query as it were, but change the input. See the last two code snippets. Before the query I set `$password = hash('sha256', $salt.$_POST['password']);`. This means _within_ the query it will now compare the generated hash with the hash stored within the database and it should return the only matching user, or no record, if the username/password doesn't match any existing user.

Comment: @KingCrunch Oh, I'm sorry dude. I must be tired-.- 
- but still, it looks like it's not working. I really don't get it -.-

Comment: As far as I can see this is exactly, what you did and what should be fine, yes.

Comment: @KingCrunch Ok, it's working now. I'm sorry for my nabness. I guess i'm just tired or something. And I'm very thankful for your patience with me.

Comment: I don't know why but the hash with sha256 works only when creating hash but when I check password it didn't

Answer (score 3):

You're storing an encrypted password, but your select query is looking for the unencrypted password.

Just get the matching username (without a password condition) - usernames are unique, right?:

```
$sql= "SELECT * FROM members WHERE username='$username'";  
$result=mysql_query($sql);    
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);  
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);  
$password = $_POST['password'];  
$salt = "lollol";  
$auth_user = hash('sha256', $salt.$password);  
if($row["password"] == $auth_user){  
    echo "Logged in";  
} else {  
    echo "Not logged in";  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$password = $_POST['password'];

// This should be the users actual salt after you've found the user
// in the database by username or email, or other means
$salt = $users_stored_salt;

// This should be the exact method you use to salt passwords on creation
// Consider creating a functon for it, you must use the same salt
// on creation and on validation
$hashed_password = hash('sha256', $salt.$password.$salt);

// This is the user's hashed password, as stored in the database
$stored_password = $users_stored_password;

// We compare the two strings, as they should be the same if given the
// same input and hashed the same way
if ($stored_password === $hashed_password){
    echo "Logged in";
} else {
    echo "Not logged in";
}
```

Missed your edit, but hope this helps.

**EDIT**: I see you aren't storing unique hashes.

If you are looking up the user by password, you need to hash the password in your query the same way it was stored:

```
$salt = $your_salt;

$hashed_password = hash('sha256', $salt.$_POST['password']);

$sql= "SELECT * FROM members WHERE username='$username' and password='$hashed_password'";
```

Otherwise, you could look up by unique username (not by password) and just compare the hashed input to the value of the stored password.

> I'm very confused right now. How should my login_ac.php look like, if I should make it with the code I gave you in the top?

Just change the query to lookup by hashed password (the way you stored it).

```
$sql= "SELECT * FROM members WHERE username='$username' and password='".hash('sha256', $salt.$_POST['password'])."'";
```

You can remove the other validation and hashing - if you found the user then you know the input is valid.

Note that this only works when you know the way you're hashing the input is the exact same way you hashed the password upon creation.

Comment: @Wesley Murch I'm very confused right now. How should my login_ac.php look like, if I should make it with the code I gave you in the top?

Comment: @Wesley Murch Hmm, I'm thinking a abit of what Ole wrote: That $password is on the both sides of == is this okay? o.O I'm very new to this sha256

Comment: @Wesley Murch - I'm hashing this way upon creation an account: $salt = "lollol";
$password = hash('sha256', $salt.$_POST['password']);

Comment: @Kolind: Take a look at [Pavling's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6431918/php-sha256-and-salt-wont-work/6432193#6432193) Sorry about confusing you with the first part, I really didn't think "lolol" was how you were actually salting passwords, I assumed it was a pseudo value representing the user's unique hash.

Comment: @Wesley Murch I already did. And right now I looks exactly as his answer. But it still doesn't work. How many VARCHAR() should my password field be like?

Comment: @Wesley well right now im just trying to get this working. And then afterwards I'll make it some unique :)

Comment: See [KingCrunch's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6431918/php-sha256-and-salt-wont-work/6432074#6432074), if you realize the logic mistake you've made, please make note of it in the comments at least. If the passwords are being stored incorrectly when you create them, that's a separate issue, but VARCHAR(255) should be fine.

Comment: @Wesley Murch Well, I've been have $salt='lolol'; all the time. even in the question.

Comment: @Wesley Murch Ok, it's working now. I'm sorry for my nabness. I guess i'm just tired or something. And I'm very thankful for your patience with me.

Answer (score 0):

It is worth checking that the field length in the database is big enough to store the whole hashed password without truncating it. You will never get a password match when logging in if the stored password is has the end missing.