# Hash 256 with uniqid mt_rand

Tags: php, hash, sha256

I'm having this login system, where I've just (finally) got hash 256 added. Earlier today I had [a very long thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6431918/php-sha256-and-salt-wont-work/6432044#comment-7548668) with @KingCrunch and some others, who helped me a lot. Thanks a lot again.

But what I wan't to do now, is that I wanna have the $salt to be unique by using:

```
$salt = uniqid(mt_rand());  $salt = uniqid(mt_rand());  
                            $password = hash('sha256', $salt.$_POST['password']);
```

Upon creating a new member, this is set, and added to database under row called "salt".

Now, when I try to login, with the created credentials it won't let me.

```
$salt = $row['salt'];
$password = hash('sha256', $salt.$_POST['password']);
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$sql= "SELECT * FROM members WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

This is my login_ac.php, where I got `$salt` to be a `row['salt']`. I don't think this ever would be successful because I haven't told which column in row salt it has to pick.

So my question is: How do I get this to work? Do have to create another query or something like that?

I need `$salt` to be a pick from `row['salt']` because I want salt to be unique.

Comment: This question is about mysql rather than hash and sha256, tags should be changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike my answer in the other question I would retrieve the whole row of the user here and compare the hashes within php (to remember: I suggested to compare it within the sql query in the other question).

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$sql= "SELECT * FROM members WHERE username='$username'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

This will retrieve the row of the user. If the username does not exists within your database `mysql_num_rows($result)` will return `0` (as usual). However, you can then recreate the hash and compare it against the one saved within the database

```
if (hash('sha256', $row['salt'] . $_POST['password']) === $row['password']) {
  // fine
}
```

Comment: Thanks once again :o) It's working. Can I in some way check if everything is working as it should? Since, when I just removed and password='$password' it would log in just fine.

Comment: @Oli sure.. but before it worked fine aswell without adding the if (hash('sha256', $row['salt'] . $_POST['password']) === $row['password']) but whatever.. It works. i'm glad.. :o) thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

As was pointed out in that previous question, if usernames are unique, you don't need to query the database on password.  Just query on username.  Then the returned row will contain both salt and password, allowing you to complete the security validation in PHP.

Comment: EDIT: And change nothing else. It seems like it works, just by removing the and password='$password'

Comment: @Kolind: You will then need to do the salt/password comparison in PHP after the result row has been returned.